# To the school vs to school

Tags: articles

As I know,
I go to school every day,(because I am a pupil)
I went to the school yesterday to meet my first teacher.
But: what if I work there?
I go to school or I go to the school.

Comment: I go to work at school everyday. I went to school to work yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, so if I work there, no definite article requires ?!

Comment: If you fill in "to school" in the search field you get almost 3000 posts http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=to+school

Answer (score 5):

You go to school for the purpose that institution effects.  In the US, this is keeping you out of the work force until you're at least 18 years old.  I can't speak for other countries.

You go to *the* school if (1) that's a place that happens to be your destination.  ("I have to go by **the** school to pick up my paycheck.") or (2) if you need to distinguish which school you attend.

> Q:  Where do you to to school?
>       A:  I go to **the** school on Main Street.

Comment: Nice explanation! +1 @deadrat!

Comment: The fact that, apparently, in the US schools act as a place to keep "you out of the work force until you're at least 18 years old," and not for educating speaks volumes!

Comment: @Jascol Well, it speaks at high volumes.  Just not coherently or grammatically.

Comment: The driveby downvoter, a curse upon this site, has struck again. Is the answer wrong? Is the answer incomplete? Is the answer misleading? Perhaps. This downvoter hasn't the courtesy to say.